# The tkinter entry widget get function in attend is not returning anything

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make an attendance app for my lecture. Here I got stuck when dealing with tkinter widget.

```
from functools import partial
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

# def focus_course(event):
#     course_name.focus_set()
# def focus_topic(event):
#     topic_name.focus_set()
# def focus_studN(event):
#     student_name.focus_set()
       
ca=StringVar
ta=StringVar
sname=StringVar
**
def attend(courseN,topicN,studN):
    ca=(courseN.get())
    ta=(topicN.get())
    sname=(studN.get())
    if((ca != "") or (ta != "") or (sname != "")):
        messagebox.showinfo("success", "all fields save")
        print("hello")
    else:
        print("printing")        
        messagebox.showinfo("error", "please enter all fields")
    **
if __name__=="__main__":
    # global submit_button
    # global course_name
    # global topic_name
    # global student_name
    top = Tk()
    top.geometry("450x300")

    # the label for user_name

    # the label for user_password
    dlabel = Label(top,
                        text = "Date").place(x = 40,
                                                y = 22)
    dlabel = Label(top,
                        text = "Course").place(x = 40,
                                                y = 60)
    topic = Label(top,
                        text = "Topic").place(x = 40,
                                                y = 100)
                        
    students = Label(top,
                        text = "Students present").place(x = 40,
                                                y = 140)


    
    courseN=StringVar()
    topicN=StringVar()
    studN=StringVar()
    
    date = DateEntry(top, width= 16, background= "magenta3", foreground= "white",bd=2)

    course_name = Entry(top,width = 30,textvariable="courseN").place(x = 150,
                                                    y = 60)
    topic_name = Entry(top,width = 30,textvariable="topicN").place(x = 150,
                                                    y = 100)
    student_name = Entry(top,width= 30,textvariable="studN").place(x=150,y=140) 
    attend=partial(attend,courseN,topicN,studN)  
    submit_button = Button(top,
                        text = "Submit",command=attend).place(x = 120,
                                                y = 180)
    print(type(course_name))
    # course_name.bind("<Return>", focus_course)
    # topic_name.bind("<Return>", focus_topic)
    # student_name.bind("<Return>", focus_studN)
    date.pack(pady=20)
    top.mainloop() 
# startapp()
```

Here I tried lot of things but never succeed in one. What can I try next?

Comment: No argument will be passed to `attend()` when it is the callback of `command` option of a `Button` widget.  Use `lambda` instead or remove those arguments from the definition of the function.

Comment: It is not clear what you are stuck on. Are you getting an error?

Comment: `ca=StringVar` (and similar) does not actually create a `StringVar`, it just creates another name for the class.  You want `ca=StringVar()`.

Comment: Note also that `textvariable="courseN"` should be `textvariable=courseN` instead.  Same for other two `Entry` widgets.